# UIImageView inside UIButton has default padding - how to remove?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

this has to be something simple but I have a UIButton of type System. I pragmatically set the image in code but when it's rendered it noticed that the image does not fill up the whole button. The box highlighted in the screen shot below is the UIImageView. The outer box around that is the UIButton.

```
self.customNavigationBar.rightButton.setImage("icon".toImage, for: .normal)
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your image asset matches the size of your button, make sure that the button's insets are set to zero:

```
let button = self.customNavigationBar.rightButton
button.setImage("icon".toImage, for: .normal)
button.imageEdgeInsets = .zero
```

If that's not the case, a more general approach would be changing the constraints of the inner `UIImageView` inside `UIButton`:

```
let button = self.customNavigationBar.rightButton
button.setImage("icon".toImage, for: .normal)
button.imageView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  button.imageView!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
  button.imageView!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1),
  button.imageView!.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerXAnchor),
  button.imageView!.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor),
])
```